# in operator always returning false

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can't figure out why this always returns false:

```
var filter_clients = [25,351];
var data = 351;
console.log(filter_clients);
console.log(data);
if(data in filter_clients) console.log('in');
else console.log('out');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4803epq/2/)

Answer (score 1):

When working with arrays, `in` operator applies to index and not to values. Examples:

```
0 in filter_clients //true
1 in filter_clients //true
2 in filter_clients //false
```

This is a way to implement what you're trying to do

```
filter_clients.indexOf(data) != -1
```

Comment: that would explain it. thanks